# App keeps crashing after button click

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent

I'm making a simple app and when I press a button that has an onClick() it crashes. I'm trying to open another activity on the button click.
Here's my onClick method from MainActivity.java:

```
public void gameActivity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here's my Button code from activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f01c00"
        android:onClick="gameActivity"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Play"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />
```

Let me know what you think's the problem. Thanks

Comment: Did you try with `startActivity(intent)` instead of `MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent)` ?

Comment: show us the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried different things like moving around the startActivity(), but nothing happened. I deleted the activity I wanted to start and made a new one. That worked. I don't know what happened, but it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

GameActivity must be registered in the AndroidManifest.